# <tspan> text </tspan> how to remove text if id or class is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove tspan element from DOM by javascript or jquery?

```
<tspan >abc.com</tspan>
```

Note: id or class is not defined for tspan and this element comes dynamically by ajax request.

In general my question is how to search for element ( in my case tspan) with specified text content?

I know :text selector but not able to apply in this case.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('tspan:contains(abc.com)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('tspan').not('[id],[class]').text('');​​​​​​​​​
```

Should get rid of it?

Comment: I have other tspan also with no id or class, i guess i should apply your query with dom element position

Comment: See my updated code, the previous wasn't tested, however this is: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/cRx4L/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("tspan").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "abc.com";
}).remove();
```

The [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector works nearly the same way, but matches a substring, which means that `tspan:contains(abc.com)` will also match elements whose inner text is `"foo abc.com bar"`, which may not be what you want.